# Importing old content to WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

A server which had WSUS running on it wouldn't boot and all attempts at a repair failed so I decided to rebuild.

Before I formatted it I backed up some key files using a Live CD. One of the things I took was nearly 500GB of WSUS updates along with the database. The domain is different, with different clients so there's not going to be whole lot of point (IMHO) in reattaching the database.

I couldn't do the `wsusutil export` procedure as the machine wouldn't boot at all.

What I'd like to do is say to my new WSUS instance and its associated database is "here's some previously downloaded content, suck that in first please" Is there a way of achieving that please? I'd obviously prefer something that's supported but am open to other suggestions too.

Could WSUS offline be of any use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binaries should be possible to move.

This is according to Microsoft

> Use your preferred method to copy WSUS update binaries in the WSUS
>   folder from the source server to the destination server (for example,
>   Windows Server Migration Tools, Windows Explorer, Xcopy, or Robocopy).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852349.aspx#BKMK_3_1

Comment: I've just copied them in, maintaining the folder structure. I'll let you know how WSUS takes it.

Comment: It may still be required to export metadata from the old server using wsusutil in order for the new server to recognize the files. But I've not found it spelled out anywhere.

Comment: That's not going to happen, see the question where I say "I couldn't do the wsusutil export procedure as the machine wouldn't boot at all."

Comment: 6 hours and 20 minutes after I started the process it came back and said the sync was complete. The folder size remains the same and the SQL database has jumped to ~2GB from its initial size. All appears well, so thank you!

Comment: Ah, I'm glad it worked!